# Plotly.js - Is there a way to draw vertical colorbar with minimum value on top and maximum on bottom?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I'm using plotly.js to plot scientific data.

I’m trying to reverse the colorscale orientation.
Plotly draw vertical colorbar with max-value on top and min value on bottom.

Is possible to invert this feature? (min-value on top and max-value on botton)

I’ve tried the “reversescale” feature, but it inverts the colorscale too.
Please help.

example

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit of a hack but I did not find any other way to do it. Basically you can create a dummy plot with the properties of the colorbar you want. In this example I am using an empty scatter plot for it. Be aware that you need to manually insert the tick values for this to work.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
 
data = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],
     [3,4,5,6,7],
     [7,8,9,6,4],
     [3,7,2,4,2]])

# Ticks to appear in the colorbar 
tickvals = [2, 5, 8]
colorscale="Viridis"

# Main plot 
trace = go.Contour(z = data, colorscale=colorscale, colorbar_tickvals=tickvals,  showscale=False)

# Dummy plot for colorbar
colorbar_trace=go.Scatter(
            x=[None],
            y=[None],
            mode='markers',
            marker=dict(
                colorscale=colorscale+'_r', 
                cmin=np.min(data),
                cmax=np.max(data),
                colorbar=dict(tickvals=tickvals, ticktext=tickvals[::-1])),
            hoverinfo='none'
            )

fig = go.Figure(data = [trace, colorbar_trace])
fig.show()
```

[Example of Inverted Colorbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29a68.png)

Comment: Hi Brener, I don't use python. But I understand.
May you clarify  this row?
`colorbar=dict(tickvals=tickvals, ticktext=tickvals[::-1]))`

Comment: Sure. This line is setting the properties of the colorbar for the dummy scatter plot. The `tickvals` key sets where the ticks will appear (in this case on values 2, 5 and 8) and the ticktext sets the text that will appear on tickvals. In this case the text will be the reversed values of tickvals, which are 8, 5 and 2. Is that clearer?

Comment: Hi Brener, I understand your solution. And It almost works. But in my application I have several dataset to plot (sometime 30). Your solution it's ok for simplier plot. Let me think about how to adapt it to my application and if I can accept your reply.

Comment: at the moment that's the only way.